# verilog: Having trouble with typedef enum, using ATOM to compile onto a tinyfpga bx

Tags: verilog, atom-editor

I am trying to create a simple program using typedef enum to count 1 to 4 on a 7-segment display. I have tried compiling but I keep getting an error saying my `typedef enum {IDLE, S1, S2, S3, S4} state_type;` and the `state_type state_reg, state_next;` lines are not correct. As said in the title, I am using Atom to put on a tinyfpga bx. I have my textbook and it is pretty much exact and after googling I don't see the issue. Also copy and pasted it into EDAplayground to see if it compiled using Aldec there and it did. So I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or I need to do something to Atom to do this. I am pretty new to verilog and stackoverflow so any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

```
module top (
    input CLK,
    output LED,
    output USBPU,
    output[0:7] SEG_LED,
    output [0:3] CT
);

reg [0:7] SEG_LED_REG;
reg [0:3] CT_REG;
reg [0:27] counter;
assign USBPU = 0;
assign SEG_LED = SEG_LED_REG;
assign CT = CT_REG;

typedef enum {IDLE, S1, S2, S3, S4} state_type;
state_type state_reg, state_next;
```

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` is a SystemVerilog construct and the Atom editor uses icarus-verilog (iverilog), which has almost no support of SystemVerilog. Use EDAplayground or the simulation tool that comes along with your FPGA tools.